# What is a typical monolayer formation time for liquid phase adsorbate on a solid surface?

Tags: surface-chemistry, adsorption

Let's say a solid is submerged in a solution of species with functional groups and a self-assembled monolayer is forming. What are the typical time scales for the formation of a continuous monolayer? (seconds, minutes, days..?)

[image] ([source](https://www.ifm.liu.se/applphys/molphys/research/self/))

For an adsorbate in *gaseous* phase and high vacuum, a rough approximation [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolayer#Formation_time) is ~1 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on concentration and other parameters. For thiols on gold, for example, a typical concentration is 1-5 mM, and formation time is 24-48 hours; "Longer assembly times tend to result in better monolayer packing." ([ref](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/content/dam/sigma-aldrich/docs/Aldrich/Instructions/1/al-266.pdf))

Comment: To emphasize the variability: I do research where I use ethanethiol + mercaptoethanol to make a gold surface hydrogen-bonding or non-hydrogen-bonding. I dip the gold-coated material in pure thiol for 30sec. We haven't characterized the packing arrangement, but our materials are noticeably non-polar (ethanethiol) or polar (mercaptoethanol).